# Show/Hide message if textarea is empty or not

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 4 textareas and a submit button that are disabled, aside each of textarea  there is a checkbox to enable them.

When checkbox is checked:

1- A message shows (Don't let this activated textarea empty).
2- Submit button remains disabled.
3- When starting to write: message hides and submit button is enabled.

When checkbox is uncheked :

1- message hides,

2- textarea related to that checkbox is cleared

3- submit button returns to disabled.

With my codes below this works perfectly for only the first textarea.
But for the others textareas i have only this problem:

1- When starting to write: message keeps showing and submit button remains disabled.
How can i solve this ?

```
//Function that handle the checkbox
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
$(".textareaalert").text("Don't let this activated textarea empty");
 $(".textareaalert").slideDown("slow"); 
$("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");   
  } else {
    $(".textareaalert").slideUp("slow");
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("textarea").val('');      
     }
 });

 //Function that handle the textarea
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
var textareaLength = $("textarea").val().length;
if ( textareaLength ==0 ) {
    $(".textareaalert").text("Don't let this activated textarea empty");
    $(".textareaalert").slideDown("slow");
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
    $(".textareaalert").slideUp("slow");
    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
```

Comment: We would be more helping to have html codes too

Comment: @Diasline Do you have message box each textarea?

Comment: No i have only one message box. Erick Philip solve the problem. but now  How can i prevent from checking a second checkbox if there is one that is already checked and the textarea related to it is empty ? I want to prevent this because there is a checked checkbox but the textarea related to it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second part of your code, you use `$("textarea").val().length`.
This line will take the value of the first textarea, and not the current.
Try this instead :

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
    var textareaLength = $(this).val().length;
    if ( textareaLength ==0 ) {
        $(".textareaalert").text("Don't let this activated textarea empty");
        $(".textareaalert").slideDown("slow");
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $(".textareaalert").slideUp("slow");
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: `attr()` and `removeAttr()` should be replaced with the newer [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

Comment: Thanks very much, you solve the problem i will accept it very soon. But something else please. How can i prevent from checking a second checkbox if there is one that is already checked and the textarea related to it is empty ? I want to prevent this because there is a checked checkbox but the textarea related to it is empty.

Comment: This isn't clear. I don't understand the other problem without html codes or rendered page. Do you have a page test ? Can you submit it into fiddle for example ?